# Get a subset of columns by row value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of users and their ratings for movies:

```
userId   movie1   movie2   movie3   movie4   movie5   movie6
0        4.1      NaN      1.0      NaN      2.1      NaN  
1        3.1      1.1      3.4      1.4      NaN      NaN  
2        2.8      NaN      1.7      NaN      3.0      NaN  
3        NaN      5.0      NaN      2.3      NaN      2.1  
4        NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
5        2.3      NaN      2.0      4.0      NaN      NaN
```

***There isnt actually a userId column in the dataframe, it's just being used for the index***

From this DataFrame, I'm trying to make a another DataFrame that only contain movies that have been rated by a specific user. For example if I wanted to make a new DataFrame of movies only rated by user with `userId == 0` the output would a dataframe with:

```
userId   movie1   movie3   movie5
0        4.1      1.0      2.1 
1        3.1      3.4      NaN  
2        2.8      1.7      3.0  
3        NaN      NaN      NaN  
4        NaN      NaN      NaN  
5        2.3      2.0      NaN
```

I know how to iterate over the columns but I dont know how to select the columns I want by checking a row value.

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve? What is the question?

Comment: @sophods The second dataframe is what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to make a function that does this but I don't know how.

Comment: So you would like some code that takes as an input the userId, and it prints the columns that are not NaN for that userId?

Comment: Yes, but it should return the dataframe, not print it out.

Comment: And does it have to return all the users back (like you display above) or just a row for that particular ID?

Comment: Yes, it should return a dataframe with the same number of rows.

Comment: @CameronCheung Does the `userId` column always contain unique values?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.loc` accessor to select the particular `userId` then use `notna` to create a boolean mask which specifies the columns which does not contain `NaN` values, finally use this boolean mask to filter the columns:

```
userId = 0 # specify the userid here
df_user = df.loc[:, df.loc[userId].notna()]
```

**Details:**

```
>>> df.loc[userId].notna()

movie1     True
movie2    False
movie3     True
movie4    False
movie5     True
movie6    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool

>>> df.loc[:, df.loc[userId].notna()]

        movie1  movie3  movie5
userId                        
0          4.1     1.0     2.1
1          3.1     3.4     NaN
2          2.8     1.7     3.0
3          NaN     NaN     NaN
4          NaN     NaN     NaN
5          2.3     2.0     NaN
```

Comment: If "no rating" is indicated with a 0 instead of a NaN, what would I need to change in this code?

Comment: Simply use `s.loc[userId].ne(0)`

Comment: I made a mistake in my original question. The dataframe does not have a userId column, the userId is already being used as the index.

Comment: If the `userid` column is already index of the dataframe then that's even better it will save you an extra step of setting it as an index..Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not working for me, I can get the mask with df.loc[userId].ne(0) but with df_user = temp_matrix.loc[:, temp_matrix.loc[1].ne(0)] it just returns the whole original dataframe. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @CameronCheung Lets discuss [`here`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228374/ds5)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
import pandas as pd

user0 = df.iloc[0,:]       #select the first row
flags = user0.notna()      #flag the non NaN values
flags = flags.tolist()     #convert to list instead of series
newdf = df.iloc[:,flags]   #return all rows, and the columns where flags are true
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my original question. The dataframe does not have a userId column, the userId is already being used as the index.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and `loc` the userId of interest into a new `df` keeping only the relevant columns.

Then `pd.concat` the new `df` with the other userId's and keep columns (movies)  of your userId that you selected:

```
user = 0 # set your userId

a = df.loc[[user]].dropna(axis=1)
b = pd.concat([a, (df.drop(a.index))[[i for i in a.columns]]])
```

Which prints:

```
b
        movie1  movie3  movie5
userId                        
0         4.10    1.00    2.10
1         3.10    3.40     NaN
2         2.80    1.70    3.00
3          NaN     NaN     NaN
4          NaN     NaN     NaN
5         2.30    2.00     NaN
```

Note that I have set the `index` to be `userId` as you specified.